# Open Print Dialog on Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

The VBA code below opens the print dialog on Windows but is not working on Mac Excel 2011, giving a **runtime error 1004** on the line `Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show`

```
Private Sub cbPrint_Click()
Dim Caption As String

If formPrintOptions.Frame1.ActiveControl.Value Then
    Caption = formPrintOptions.Frame1.ActiveControl.Caption

    formPrintOptions.Hide
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show

    Select Case Caption
        Case "Id1"
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("FrontPage", "Id1")).PrintOut Preview:=True
        Case "Id2"
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("FrontPage", "Id2")).PrintOut Preview:=True
        Case "Id3"
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("FrontPage", "Id3")).PrintOut Preview:=True
        Case "Id4"
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("FrontPage", "Id4")).PrintOut Preview:=True
        Case Else
    End Select
Else
    MsgBox "None selected"
End If
Unload formPrintOptions

End Sub
```

Please can someone advise if there is a way to open the print dialog window on Mac Excel 2011?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/553760-application-substitute-mac.html) there are three options:

(*Quote*)

> In that case, that functionality is "on the top" of the normal Print screen for Mac.
>   "On top" both in the sense that no subordinate dialog needs to be invoked and it is above all the other options on the Print Dialog box.

or

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show
```

or

```
MsgBox MacScript(PrintSetupMacScript())

Function PrintSetupMacScript() As String
PrintSetupMacScript = "try"
PrintSetupMacScript = PrintSetupMacScript & vbLf & "tell application ""System Preferences"" "
PrintSetupMacScript = PrintSetupMacScript & vbLf & "    reveal pane ""Print & Fax"" "
PrintSetupMacScript = PrintSetupMacScript & vbLf & "    activate"
PrintSetupMacScript = PrintSetupMacScript & vbLf & "    repeat while (name of window 1) = ""Print & Fax"" "
PrintSetupMacScript = PrintSetupMacScript & vbLf & "   end repeat"
PrintSetupMacScript = PrintSetupMacScript & vbLf & "end tell"
PrintSetupMacScript = PrintSetupMacScript & vbLf & "return true"
PrintSetupMacScript = PrintSetupMacScript & vbLf & "on error"
PrintSetupMacScript = PrintSetupMacScript & vbLf & "return false"
PrintSetupMacScript = PrintSetupMacScript & vbLf & "end try"
End Function
```

not having a mac to test these on, I can't vouch for their mileage