# Excel Print Macro

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-2016

I am using the following macro to print from an Excel file.

```
Sub PrintPDF()

bTemp = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show

End Sub
```

Works fine when user prints, but when the user clicks 'Cancel' in the print dialogue it throws this error:

> ```
> Run-time error '1004':
> Method 'Show' of object 'Dialog' failed
> ```

Is there is a line of code I can add to my macro to prevent this error when the user clicks <kbd>Cancel</kbd>?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Is it exactly what you have or this is part of your code?

Comment: @Masoud this is the only line of code I am using for the print macro.  Running on Excel 2016 for Mac.

Comment: Add `Exit Sub` after this line. That's a very naive suggestion but give it a shot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326446/open-print-dialog-on-mac

Comment: Did you try adding On Error Resume Next just after Sub PrintPDF()?

Comment: @sktneer that fixed it -- thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this code fixes the error:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

Full macro:

```
Sub PrintPDF()

On Error Resume Next
bTemp = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show

End Sub
```